# How to return a list the last vertex within each path object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to build a chaining mechanism with my query and I want to start my next invocation from the end of the previous. I've tried using the `by` step, but I can't seem to get it to work or do what I would like. What is the best way to get the last vertex in all the paths from the below query?

`g.V(1).repeat(out()).times(2).emit().path();`

If this returned:

```
[v[1], v[2], v[3]]
[v[1], v[3], v[4]]
```

All I want is:

```
v[3]
v[4]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the `tail` of a `path`

```java
gremlin> g.V(44).out().out().limit(5).path()
==>[v[44],v[8],v[47]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[48]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[49]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[51]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[52]]

gremlin> g.V(44).out().out().limit(5).path().tail(local)
==>v[47]
==>v[48]
==>v[49]
==>v[51]
==>v[52]
```